# WlanConnect(), how to connect to and open wireless access point

Tags: c++, wlanapi

in order to connecto to an open access point I fill the WLAN_CONNECTION_PARAMETERS structure as below

```
WLAN_CONNECTION_PARAMETERS ConnectionParameters;
ConnectionParameters.wlanConnectionMode = wlan_connection_mode_discovery_unsecure;
ConnectionParameters.strProfile         = L"";
ConnectionParameters.pDot11Ssid         = &Dot11Ssid;
ConnectionParameters.pDesiredBssidList  = nullptr;
ConnectionParameters.dot11BssType       = dot11_BSS_type_independent;
ConnectionParameters.dwFlags            = WLAN_CONNECTION_ADHOC_JOIN_ONLY;
```

The `WlanConnect()` function returns `ERROR_SUCCESS`.

The `NotificationCallback()` function prints:

```
wlan_notification_acm_connection_start
Currently connecting to "BT.03" using profile "BT.03" **// Correct**
WLAN_NOTIFICATION_SOURCE_ACM
**wlan_notification_acm_connection_attempt_fail**
The connection failed. wlanReasonCode:  163851
The reason is "La rete specificata non è disponibile."
```

Where is the error?

Have you got a piece of code to connect to a new open wireless access point with a specific ssid?

Comment: Please post the code that sets-up `Dot11Ssid`.

Comment: Your code says `strProfile = L""` but your output display says "BT.03". Please post your **actual** code or make it clear you're obfuscating secrets.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation for `WLAN_CONNECTION_PARAMETERS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wlanapi/ns-wlanapi-wlan_connection_parameters) states that `strProfile` should be set to `NULL` when using `wlan_connection_mode_discovery_unsecure`, but your code sets it to `L""`.

> If `wlanConnectionMode` is set to `wlan_connection_mode_discovery_secure` or `wlan_connection_mode_discovery_unsecure`, then `strProfile` should be set to `NULL`.

So change your code to this:

```
ConnectionParameters.strProfile = NULL;
```

Comment: @DenisGottardello `nullptr` isn't the same thing as `NULL` though. Win32 is still a C (not C++) API, so always use `NULL` instead of `nullptr` when using Win32.

Comment: @DenisGottardello Just edit your original question.

Answer (score 0):

ConnectionParameters.strProfile= nullptr;

don't resolve.

The solution is to add

```
memset(&ConnectionParameters, 0, sizeof(WLAN_CONNECTION_PARAMETERS));
```